# How to match file in directory when match with temp.getstat using java

Tags: java

I'm writing java coding if file 'id' in sql server table matches filename of file on local directory..how to scan the file and check the filename is match without using for loop.

```
String pathJ = "C:\\sampleDirectory"; 
    NewsContentObj[] newObj =   firstTimeRetrieveRecordFromDB();
    for (NewsContentObj temp : newObj) {

         File dir = new File("C:\\sampleDirectory");
         File[] files = dir.listFiles();
         Arrays.sort(files);

         for (File file : files){
             String path1 = file.getAbsolutePath();
                String path = file.getName();

             if(temp.getStat().equals(file)){
                  System.out.println("first path:" + file );
                //System.out.println("first path1:" + files[i].getName());
                  cacheStaticL(pathJ,path);
             }
              //}
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `match file in directory when match with existing file in directory` Huh? Both files exist in your directory? Your question is unclear.

Comment: First, it will retrieve record from a SQL table. After get the result will set to bean file. If temp.getstat() is matching with the directory  "C:\\sampleDirectory", then it will run  cacheStaticL(pathJ,path);, I dun wan using for loop two time, because will affected performance. is it have scan file can be use or others option?

Comment: As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032470/how-to-match-file-in-directory-when-match-with-temp-getstat-using-java/41032537#comment69434698_41032537) comment, you should **accept the answer by clicking the "right" tick mark** under the score displayed on left side. Additionally you may upvote the answer as well if the answer was good enough for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code to check if file exist in given directory

```
boolean check = new File(directory, temp).exists();
```

Comment: After try, answer is false although the file is exist in directory

Comment: are you trying with filename.extension example filename.txt

Comment: Thanks, i get the result. my file is PDF file. After the result is true, how to get the file because the next is need using that file to extract pdf. it also need using for loop to get the file right?

Comment: I think i know de...direct using that temp.pdf file for method like  cacheStaticL(pathJ,temp.getStat() +".pdf"); correct right?

Comment: You have directory and file name, using filename and directory you can easily read file, Using java.io api

Comment: @SharonWong you can accept answer if it resolves your issue.

Comment: @Sharon Wong `I think I know de`.. looks like you are from sg.